# SwiftMessage: how to handle action when user tap on outside of message view?

Tags: swift, swiftmessages

I'm using SwiftMessage in my project. when the specific message is showing on the screen, I want when the user tap on outside of the message view (anywhere else on message view), some actions happening. how can I do this?

**update**

I forgot to say I'm using SwiftMessage with one button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to add an action on tap outside of the `MessageView`.

However, if your `dimMode` is `interactive` (has tap outside to dismiss enabled) you can easily catch `.willHide` and `.didHide` events using `eventListeners` of `SwiftMessages.Config`:

```
let view = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .cardView)

var config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
config.dimMode = .gray(interactive: false)
config.eventListeners.append { event in
    switch event {
    case .willHide:
        // Handle will hide
    case .didHide:
        // Handle did hide
    default:
        break
    }
}
SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
```

Those events will be triggered on tap outside of the `MessageView`.

**Update**: In your particular case where you have a button which have a different action from the tap outside action, you can use something like this:

```
func showMessageView(buttonHandler: @escaping () -> Void, dismiss: @escaping () -> Void) {
    var buttonTapped = false
    let view = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .cardView)
    view.buttonTapHandler = { sender in
        buttonHandler()
        buttonTapped = true
    }

    var config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
    config.dimMode = .gray(interactive: false)
    config.eventListeners.append { event in
        if !buttonTapped, event == .didHide {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
    SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
}
```

That way when the button is tapped the `dismiss` closure will never run.

Comment: I used this way but the problem is when the user tap on button ( sorry I forgot to say I'm using SwiftMessage with button), the event will be called too.

Comment: @behrad I also had the same issue once. Please, check my updated answer.

Comment: I like this solution :)